# CSS: Target the <td> below a specific <th> using #id or .class NOT nth-child

Tags: css, html-table

I want text in all **TD** below ONE SPECIFIC **TH** to be BOLD

The table has dynamic columns numbers/positions so I cannot use nth-child()

Example below:

```html
 <table>
  <thead>
<th id="th_name">Name</th>
<th>Price</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<tr>
  <td>Apple</td>
  <td>$10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Banana</td>
  <td>$10</td>
</tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

- `<TD>`s below NAME should be BOLD

Is it possible to do this with only CSS not Javascript?

Comment: BTW don't use multi `tbody` use `tr` instead

Comment: As I know it impossible in css!

Comment: FYI: Want to do this without assigning an ID/selector tag to the <td> to reduce page file size for large tables with 5-10,000 rows

Comment: @sushil Please do not add deprecated tags to questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's possible in this way to set one column with bold text...

However regarding the title:

> CSS: Target the `<td>` below a specific `<th>` using #id or .class NOT
>   nth-child

With the `<col>` element it is possible to target and style a particular column, but unfortunately only a few properties are available for styling (`font-weight` isn't one of them)

So it is possible to target and style particular columns, but only in a very limited way.

Here's a demo:

```css
.name {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: orange;
}
.th_name {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col class="name">
    <col class="price">
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <th class="th_name">Name</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td>$10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Banana</td>
      <td>$10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>$15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cherry</td>
      <td>$20</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

From the [CSS 2.1 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#columns):

> ...Nevertheless, some aspects of cells can be influenced by setting
>   properties on columns.
>
> The following properties apply to column and column-group elements:
>
> **'border'**
>
> The various border properties apply to columns only if
>   'border-collapse' is set to 'collapse' on the table element. In that
>   case, borders set on columns and column groups are input to the
>   conflict resolution algorithm that selects the border styles at every
>   cell edge.
>
> **'background'**
>
> The background properties set the background for cells in the column,
>   but only if both the cell and row have transparent backgrounds. See
>   "Table layers and transparency."
>
> **'width'**
>
> The 'width' property gives the minimum width for the column.
>
> **'visibility'**
>
> If the 'visibility' of a column is set to 'collapse', none of the
>   cells in the column are rendered, and cells that span into other
>   columns are clipped. In addition, the width of the table is diminished
>   by the width the column would have taken up. See "Dynamic effects"
>   below. Other values for 'visibility' have no effect.

Comment: Thanks this is the closest I've seen. Why does CSS not make this more expanded to offer the full range of css for children of a column?

Comment: @pablorenato that's a question for the guys that wrote the spec ;) - but remember, that was a long time ago, maybe the spec authors just didn't think people would need any more than that.

Comment: And on that note here is the answer. CSS4 (well level 4 of the selector module) will have it. Sigh. If only they had thought of this with CSS3!!!! http://css4.rocks/grid-structural-pseudo-classes.php

Answer (score 1):

There is no parent-child relationship between your `th` and `td` and you can't set it with CSS only. You can just add class to each td you need.

```css
.bold{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th id="th_name">Name</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="bold">Apple</td>
      <td>$10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="bold">Banana</td>
      <td>$10</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Or use `:first-child`

```css
td:first-child{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th id="th_name">Name</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td>$10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Banana</td>
      <td>$10</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks. I want to avoid using first or nth child with an explicit hard coded number. Because the position of columns can change. Also want to avoid adding a selector attribute to the TD to keep the page file size smaller when there are 10,000 table rows downloading. Based on research it seems we must use Javascript to do this?

Comment: If you want to reduce the page size (in order to reduce the traffic), don't generate the code on the server side, generate it on the client, for example: Angular, React etc.... this way you only pass the raw data which is much lighter, and the client renders it and generate the full HTML.

Comment: Thanks will look into this also